# How to assign the default document to a variable

Tags: excel, autocad, vba

#### Background

Using VBA run from Excel to grab/open a AutoCAD and start drawing in a new Drawing.

#### What I have so far

What I have tried so far is taken from stuff I have found in various parts of the net:

```
Sub Open_AutoCad(NewFile As AcadDocument, ACAD As AcadApplication)

'Dim MyAcadPath As String
'Dim bReadOnly As Boolean


    On Error Resume Next
    Set ACAD = GetObject(, "autocad.Application")
    If (Err <> 0) Then
        Err.Clear
        Set ACAD = CreateObject("autocad.Application")
        If (Err <> 0) Then
            MsgBox "Could Not Load AutoCAD!", vbExclamation
            End
        End If
'*****************************************
    Set NewFile = ACAD.Documents.active  <-need correct syntax for active document
'*****************************************
    Else
        Set NewFile = ACAD.Documents.Add
    End If
    
    ACAD.Visible = True



'    PREVIOUS OPEN METHOD THAT IS HARD CODED FILE PATH       
'    MyAcadPath = "c:\Temp\Blank Drawing.dwg"
'    bReadOnly = True
'    Set NewFile = ACAD.Documents.Open(MyAcadPath, bReadOnly)
'
'    If (NewFile Is Nothing) Then
'ErrorMessage:
'        If NewFile = "False" Then End
'            MsgBox "Could not find the required file that should be located at" & vbCr & MyAcadPath & vbCr & "Please rename or relocated the specified file as needed."
'        End
'    End If
  


    'close AutoCAD Process
    'ACAD.Quit
    
    'Set ACAD = Nothing
    'Set NewFile = Nothing
        
End Sub
```

I initially was opening a drawing from a hard coded path, but that is not what I want to have happen.  I want to instead grab the default template file that happens to be set up in autocad and use it instead.  thought being it saves having to make sure all users have the hard coded path.

#### Problem

I opted to use the ACAD.Documents.Add method to add the default template file and it works great.  The problem is that AutoCAD automatically creates Drawing1 when opening (at least on my system) when a specific file is not being opened.  As a result when I hit .Add I would wind up with Drawing2, and all work would be performed in drawing2.  So to avoid this, I am only using the .Add method if AutoCAD already exists/up and running.  And that aspect is working fine.  How do I assign Drawing1 to the variable Newfile when it was already created by AutoCAD as part of its opening routine?

#### Updated code based on Chris' suggestions:

```
Sub Open_AutoCad(NewFile As AcadDocument, ACAD As AcadApplication)

'Dim MyAcadPath As String
'Dim bReadOnly As Boolean


    On Error Resume Next
    Set ACAD = GetObject(, "autocad.Application")
    On Error Goto 0
    If ACAD=Nothing Then
        Err.Clear
        Set ACAD = CreateObject("autocad.Application")
        If (Err <> 0) Then
            MsgBox "Could Not Load AutoCAD!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
'*****************************************
    Set NewFile = ACAD.Documents.activedocument
'*****************************************
    Else
        Set NewFile = ACAD.Documents.Add
    End If
    
    ACAD.Visible = True
   
End Sub
```

Comment: [See acad site](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/AutoCAD-ActiveX/files/GUID-161FD7E5-B739-4E09-8430-BA04A6298703-htm.html)

Comment: A couple of pointers:  1) after GetObject reset error handling (On Error GoTo 0). Then test If ACAD Is Nothing ( rather than Err <> 0).  2) dont use End, use Exit Sub.

Comment: And why not use early binding?

Comment: Thank you Chris.   I did not stumble on this particular post in my searches.   I did hit other AutoCAD VBA documentation though.  What search terms did you use?

Comment: @chrisneilsen I am very much learning VBA.  Last programming language I used was turbo pascal.  THe other unfortunate part about this project I am working on is I only get to touch it every 2-4 weeks when I has some spare free time around the house.

Comment: Search term: acad vba active drawing.  Good luck with the vba learning curve